# this.offset is not a function within a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The error is that `_this.offset` is not a function. I logged this to the console and it was the `<li>` element I clicked on, so I am confused why this would not work.

```js
$('.item').click(function(e) {
  var _this = this;
  var topx = _this.offset().top;
  var leftx = _this.offset().left;
  var moveArea = $('#replace').offset().top;
  var moveLeft = $('#replace').offset().left;
  var moveUp = topx - moveArea - 50;
  _this.css('position', 'absolute').css('top', moveUp).css('zIndex', 50).css('left', leftx);
  _this.animate({
    top: -50,
    left: moveLeft
  }, 300)
});
```

```css
#replace {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

#list {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="replace">
  Replace this
</div>

<ul id="list">
  <li class="item">TEST</li>
  <li class="item">TEST</li>
  <li class="item">TEST</li>
</ul>
```

I also want to create an animation such that the item I click in the list moves up to replace the green "Replace this" box, if someone could help with that too.

I created a jsfiddle to show the error: https://jsfiddle.net/v5fjjwmj/2/

Comment: use $(this) instead of this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`this` (and hence `_this`) inside your event handler refers to a DOMElement which doesn't have the `offset()` method as that's part of jQuery. To fix this you can create a jQuery object using `$(this)`:

```
$('.item').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var topx = $this.offset().top;
    var leftx = $this.offset().left;
    var moveArea = $('#replace').offset().top;
    var moveLeft = $('#replace').offset().left;
    var moveUp = topx - moveArea - 50;

    $this.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': moveUp,
        'zIndex': 50,
        'left': leftx
    }).animate({
        top: -50,
        left: moveLeft
    }, 300)
});
```

Also note the use of the object provided to a single `css()` call over multiple calls to the same method.

Comment: Your answer is a lifesaver. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. that is a great answer.

Answer (score 7):

Replace these two lines:

```
var topx = _this.offset().top;
var leftx = _this.offset().left;
```

with:

```
var topx = _this.offsetTop;
var leftx = _this.offsetLeft;
```

As `.offset()` is a jquery function and `_this` is a DOM element.

---

Also for your `.css` line you have to wrap `_this` in `$(...)` again because `_this` is a DOM element and **not a jQuery object.